# Insert values into custom field's extra columns in database

Tags: entities

I'm new to drupal 7.

I've create a custom field with extra columns via field api, and create the field well(via UI), but I can't "save" it while using the field.

I've google for it and found some keywords like

```
hook_field_storage_write()、hook_field_attach_submit()
```

But still can't get what I want.
Can someone give me advices?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details how did you implement schema, widget, formatter etc.
I guess this link can be helpful for you http://www.slideshare.net/zugec/fields-in-core-how-to-create-a-custom-field

Comment: [schema]: using hook_field_schema, with 4 extra columns in .install files and MigrateFieldHandler in .module
[widget]: one column, #type=>textfield
[formatter]: hyperlink (function l)

Comment: great) what was the problem?

Comment: I can't insert values in my custom field until I found hook_node_presave()